# Can C# event handlers be "overloaded"?

Tags: c#, event-handling, overloading

I have many winforms `TextBox` that let user input values. I'm writing event handlers for the `LostFocus` event and they all follow the same pattern except they change a different field variable of the current `Form` instance. I'm repeating blocks of code with very minor differences too many times.

I've seen people refer to Reflection but it seems a little beyond my grasp as a novice C# programmer

```
class myForm: Form
{
  public myForm()
  {
    // .... codes
    textbox1.LostFocus += OnExit;
    textbox2.LostFocus += OnExit;
    // repeats above for all textbox;
  }
  protected int tb1value;
  protected int tb2value;
  //... lots of fields but names relate to each textbox control
  protected void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    TextBox s = sender as TextBox;
    /* how do I do below??
    find the variable/field that relates to this textbox(sender)
    change that field's value
    if sender is textbox1, then find tb1value and change it
    */
  }
}
```

How do I avoid writing a `OnExit` for each `TextBox`?

Comment: You should at least on occassion consult the online documentation (just tap F1): `Typically, the GotFocus and LostFocus events are only used when updating UICues or when writing custom controls. Instead the Enter and Leave events should be used for all controls...`

Comment: FYI: LostFocus was deprecated in favor of the Leave event.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I'll handle `Enter` and `Leave` instead

Answer (score 1):

Make a map:

```
class myForm: Form
{
    // you weren't specific about the type of the `tb?value` fields
    private map As Dictionary<TextBox, Control>;

    public myForm()
    {
        // .... codes
        textbox1.LostFocus += OnExit;
        textbox2.LostFocus += OnExit;
        // repeats above for all textbox;

        map = new Dictionary<TextBox, Control> {
             {textbox1, tb1value},
             {textbox2, tb2value}
             //...
        };
    }

    protected tb1value;
    protected tb2value;
```

Now the `OnExit` handler can reference the map:

```
protected void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox s = sender as TextBox;
    Control c = map[s];
    c.Text = "some new value from s";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is to set `Tag` property of the TextBox to the text you want to appear when losing focus. Then, you do this:

```
protected void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox s = sender as TextBox;
    s.Text = s.Tag.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach I know is this:

```
class myForm: Form
{
  public myForm()
  {
    // .... codes
    textbox1.LostFocus += (s, e) => tb1value = 1;
    textbox2.LostFocus += (s, e) => tb2value = 2;
    // repeats above for all textbox;
  }
  protected int tb1value;
  protected int tb2value;
  //... lots of fields but names relate to each textbox control
}
```

You're basically losing the `OnExit` method (which is not named correctly according to standard .NET naming standards).

If there's a lot more work going on inside `OnExit` then try something like this:

```
class myForm: Form
{
  public myForm()
  {
    // .... codes
    textbox1.LostFocus += (s, e) => TextBoxes_LostFocus(0);
    textbox2.LostFocus += (s, e) => TextBoxes_LostFocus(1);
    // repeats above for all textbox;
  }
  protected int[] tbvalues;

    protected void TextBoxes_LostFocus(int index)
    {
        tbvalues[index] = 42;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use lambdas as event handlers:

```
textbox1.Leave += (s, e) => tb1value = Int32.Parse(((TextBox)s).Text);
textbox2.Leave += (s, e) => tb2value = Int32.Parse(((TextBox)s).Text);
```

If your code is more complex then you could call a method to handle the hooking of the lambda(s):

```
ActivateTextBox(textbox1, (v) => tb1value = v);
ActivateTextBox(textbox2, (v) => tb2value = v);

void ActivateTextBox(TextBox textBox, Action<int> update)
{
    textBox.Enter += (s, e) =>
    {
        textBox.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
    };
    textBox.Leave += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(textBox.Text, out int value))
        {
            update(value);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    };
}
```